# Webview Loading - Content finished loading check

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, heroku

I'm creating an app hosted on a cloud service(heroku) that sleeps every 30 minutes of inactivity. The app shows a loading activity when the page loads. Since the server sleeps every 30 minutes of no request to it, response time may vary from 2 to 12 seconds. I'm trying to find a way to know if content fully loaded with CSS and JS. onPageFinished event doesn't work for me, most times I get a blank page.

```
 public void load(){
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl(serverURL);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            LoadingActivity la = new LoadingActivity();
            if(la.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this))
                LoadingActivity.current.finish();
            /* This event is called before all content loaded */
        }
    });
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set WebChrome client on webView, it has load percentage event, u can try listen to that one.

Comment: WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) 
      {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);            }
        });

Comment: I still get a blank page for few seconds. I checked if newProgress == 100.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest thing to do is just call the java from the javascript document ready function.